# Java is this check for uniqueness sufficient?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
    double[] a = new double[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        double randomNum = Math.random() * 100;
        a[i] = randomNum;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                i--;
                break;
            }
        }
```

I have a block of code above that checks for the uniqueness of a `double` in an array. I have run my program a couple of times and the results are what I desire.

However, I went back and traced the program and may have found a flaw in the code. If the same number gets randomly generated twice in succession I think that the above code would fail. Say the first double is `1.0`, then the next two randomly generated doubles just so happened to be `1.0` as well... the inner for loop would never get executed because of the condition that `j < i. i` gets decremented from 1 to 0 so the check will fail for the second number that gets generated.

Could someone confirm whether or not this is true since I am new to Java.

Comment: Try pulling up a debugger and see if that situation occurs or not. If you want a much easier way to guarantee uniqueness, use a `Set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you have is correct. The inner loop will run up to the *index just before the number you just generated*. If you just generated a[5] the inner loop will compare a[5] with a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3] and a[4].

Because i gets immediately incremented again after decrementing it (when the outer loop continues) it won't fail the check like you're wondering. If a[1] turns out to be a duplicate of a[0], i gets decremented from 1 to 0 then immediately incremented back to 1.

As a side note, since you are generating doubles you will almost never get a duplicate unless you generate a ridiculously large number of them.

Comment: The inner will get skipped if i = 0 since the condition is i <  j. I don't see how that works. Could you explain?

Comment: @StevenN It won't fail the check because i gets immediately incremented after you decrement it. i gets decremented from 1 to 0 and then immediately incremented back to 1.

Comment: i immediately gets incremented because it reached the end of the for loop due to the break statement right?

Comment: Yeah you break the inner loop and the next statement is the i++ in the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the [Collection.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method (or write something similar for your Array) from a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) because they prevent duplicates. A [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) (e.g. [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)) does have performance optimizations for some use cases.

Answer (score 0):

use Set rather than array.

```
 Set<Double> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
         set.add(Math.random() * 100)
    }
    System.out.println(set);
```

now you have only unique value